# How do I stop background color code from overriding round corners code in xml?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have encoded in layout.xml the following button

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonCorrection"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="Undo last entry"
    android:textSize="@dimen/button_text_size"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAgainstBackground"
    android:background="@drawable/clickcorrectionbutton"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textviewPlayerB"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textviewPlayerA"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textviewPlayerA" />
```

The clickcorrectionbuttion.xml is used to set the button's background color and the rounding of its corners:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners android:radius="10dp"></corners>
            <solid android:color="@color/colorCorrection"></solid>
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

This works perfectly. **However**, the java code at some point in the app calls for the button to change color and text. That code reads as follows ...

> buttonCorrection.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.colorAgainstBackground));
>   buttonCorrection.setTextColor(getColor(R.color.colorAgainstButton));
>   buttonCorrection.setText("Select button");

The problem is that, when that java code is invoked, it does indeed change the background color and text of the button as desired, but it **also deletes the round corners**. It somehow seems to override what's in the selector. **How can the corners be kept rounded?**

Comment: Use `buttonCorrection.getDrawable().setColorFilter(COLOR_HERE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);` instead of `setBackgroundColor`

Comment: @akaki unfortunately getDrawable() "method cannot be resolved"

Comment: sorry! `getBackground()`

Answer (score 0):

I made a selector xml for each of the button states. The background selection java code now looks like

buttonCorrection.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.clickcorrectionbutton))

and

buttonCorrection.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.clickcorrectionbuttonnonactive))